# How to get content below background-image with z-index of -1?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using bootstrap and right now I have a banner image below my navbar with a title header over it. It works fine but now I'm not sure how to get content below my image. For example, the content div is overlapping the image and not going below it like a block element.

Do I need to use an img tag instead of using the css background property?

**HTML**

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default" role="navigation">
...
</nav>

<div class="img-banner"> 
</div>

<div class="container">
  <h1>TITLE</h1>

  <div class="content">
    <p>new section/block of text</p>
  </div>

</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.img-banner { 
  height: 800px; 
  background: url('../img/background.jpg') no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  background-attachment: fixed;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  top: 0;
  z-index: -1;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try position:relative instead of position:absolute for the img-banner. I think this is the fix.

Comment: Thanks, that worked! Do you know how I would move the image to the the top though? I want the navbar to overlap the image.

Comment: You can use negative margin-top for img-banner. it should be equal to the nav-bar height. so obviously you need to know the height of the nav-bar:  .img-banner {
  position: relative;
  z-index: -1;
  margin-top: -[nav-bar height]px; 
}

Comment: That worked but now text-align: center for h1 doesn't center and is offset. Know how to fix that?

Comment: If you could post the full HTML/CSS file, I could do a better help, however from what you explain, I guess replacing margin-top: - with top : - can fix the problem. Please check and let me know.